# error converting varchar to numeric in update string

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am having an issue with my update code, error converting varchar to numeric is creating an exception. It is dealing with two tables.

table1(WEB_ADDRESS) consists of address information That is sent to a geocoding API service.

```
|PKID | ADDRESS_ID | ADDRESS_1 | CITY | etc...
```

table2(WEB_ADDRESS_GEO) consists lattitudes and longitudes recieved from the API service.

```
ADDRESS_ID | Lat | Lng
```

I need to update the rows of data in table 2 with lats and lngs to match the address data in table 1.

here is the code here

```
  using (SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(context))
  {
      myConnection.Open();
      string strQueryUpdate = "UPDATE WEB_ADDRESS_GEO SET Lat = '" + strLat + "', Lng = '" + strLng + "'" + "WHERE ADDRESS_ID=" + row.ADDRESS_ID;
      SqlCommand myCommandUpdate = new SqlCommand(strQueryUpdate, myConnection);
      myCommandUpdate.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

the column ADDRESS_ID is of type VarChar, Lat and Lng are of type decimal.

Note : sql injection is avoided as there will never be user input.

Comment: You will feel the wrath of gods of SQL injection by doing that string concatenation instead of using prepared statements/parameters...

Comment: Note: sql injection is not the only reason to use parameterized commands. For example parameters have explicit types so you can avoid type problems such as you are having here (or at least they are easier to see).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `ADDRESS_ID` is `VarChar`, you need to use single quotes with it like;

```
"WHERE ADDRESS_ID= '" + row.ADDRESS_ID + "'"
```

If `Lat` and `Lng` are `decimal`, you don't need to use single quotes with them.

```
SET Lat = " + strLat + ", Lng = " + strLng
```

As a better way, use [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/). This kind of string concatenations are open for [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

```
using(SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(context))
using(SqlCommand myCommandUpdate = conn.CreateCommand())
{
   myCommandUpdate.CommandText = @"UPDATE WEB_ADDRESS_GEO SET Lat = @lat, Lng = @lng 
                                  WHERE ADDRESS_ID = @address";
   myCommandUpdate.Parameters.Add(@lat, SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = strLat;
   myCommandUpdate.Parameters.Add(@lng, SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = strLng;
   myCommandUpdate.Parameters.Add(@address, SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = row.ADDRESS_ID;
   myConnection.Open();
   myCommandUpdate.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

But from your variable names, `strLat` and `strLng` really sounds like some character values, not numerical values. It is the opposite your `row.ADDRESS_ID` value. *Mostly* the variable contains `ID` as a name used in numeric values, not characters.

Comment: Even if not worrying about SQL injection (because you 100% trust the source) parameterized queries are better at dealing with types because you don't need to worry about whether you are quoting correctly and such like.

Comment: NB. I think you should remove the ADDRESS_ID comments. IDs are usually numeric and there is no reason to suspect that it isn't in this case and it obscures the real issue that you mention next.

Comment: It looks like the best answer for the question is really just to use parametrized queries. So I will do that.

Comment: @RyeNyeTheWebSiteGuy What is the error  exactly? Can you please be more specific?

Comment: @Chris Exactly. Their names really sounds as opposite as their types as I mentioned.

Comment: The ID's look like 70-00001223

Comment: @RyeNyeTheWebSiteGuy This doesn't look to me like a numeric value. Using `VarChar` type will be good choice.